# How can a catch block catch a reference to a temporary variable in an other scope?

Tags: c++

You could have a try. The program below compiles and runs smoothly. The address of variable `ex` in the constructor is different from that of `e`, a temporary variable in the catch block. Yet you may notice that the value of `ex` in line B is passed to `e` by reference. Could anyone explain what's going on?

```
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>


using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;

class ThrowException;
ThrowException* TE_ptr;

class ThrowException{

    private:
        string msg;
        int b;
    public:
        ThrowException(string m="Unknown exception",int factor=0) throw(string,const char*);
        ~ThrowException(){        cout<<"destructor get called."<<endl;}
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const ThrowException&TE);
};

ThrowException::ThrowException(string m, int f) throw(string,const char*):msg(m),b(f){
    cout<<"msg="<<msg<<'\n'<<"b="<<b<<endl;
    TE_ptr=this;
    if(b==1){
        string ex("b=1 not allowed.");
        cout<<"The address of e in constructor is "<<&ex<<endl;      //A
        throw ex;
    }
}

std::ostream&operator<<(std::ostream&os, const ThrowException &TE){
    os<<TE.msg<<'\n'<<TE.b<<endl;
}
int main(){

    try{
        ThrowException a("There's nothing wrong.", 1);
    }catch(string &e){             //B
        cout<<"The address of e in first catch block is "<<&e<<endl;        //C
        cout<<"The content resided in the momery block pointed to by TE_ptr is "<<*TE_ptr<<endl;
    }

}
```

Another problem I would like to ask is when will the destructor of ThrowException object a be called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `throw` expression copies the thrown object to a safe place before leaving the local scope. The language doesn't say exactly where it is stored, just that this must work somehow (details left to the implementation).

Comment: Presumably it's designed this way because otherwise you'd have to either throw something which you'd had to allocate memory for or throw something which you then catch by value.

Comment: Well, I have another question. When will the destructor of ThrowException object get called. I've modified the code again, yet the destructor doesn't get called if ThrowException object was declared with try block.

Comment: It should be destroyed when leaving the scope where it lives. Here that would be at the end of the try block. Perhaps you don't have time to see the message when `main` also ends immediately?

Comment: @BoPersson He's throwing the exception in the constructor.  Since the object hasn't been successfully constructed, it won't be destructed.

Comment: @JamesKanze How do you determine that the ThrowException object hasn't been constructed successfully? I've added a global pointer variable of type ThrowException and assigned it the address of ThrowException when the object was constructed. It seems that the ThrowException object still exists after the exception was thrown.

Comment: @JDein By looking at the code you've posted.  An object is successfully constructed when its constructor completes.  Not before.